# Blank page shown during jQuery parsing

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have written this XML file:

```
<!--bookstore.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE reviews SYSTEM "bookstore.dtd">

<bookstore>
<location>Port Credit</location>
<address intersection="Hurontario And Lakeshore"/>
<book id="1000">
    <title> Intro to C</title>
    <copies>5</copies>
    <author name="John Fingle"/>
    <author name="Carrie Dingle"/>
<price>20.95</price>
</book>
<book id="1001">
    <title>C for Rocket Scientists</title>
    <copies>3</copies>
    <author name="Robert Johnson"/>
    <author name="B. King"/>
<price>28.95</price>
</book>
<book id="1011">
    <title>Les Miserables</title>
    <copies>5</copies>
    <author name="Victor Hugo"/>
<price>24.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

And I am trying to parse this by using this jQuery Method

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "bookstore.xml",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : processXml
        });
    });
function processXml(xml)
{
  var name = $(xml).find('location').text();
    $('#nameDiv').html(name);
}
```

and here is my HTML page,

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<div id="nameDiv">


</div>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I have checked my XML, HTML and jQuery methods, didn't seem to have any mistakes. But still it is not appending the value to the div and shows a blank page. What may be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(xml).find('location')[0].text();
```

should give you what you need.

Comment: Can you please explain, I have tried like this   var name = $(xml).find('location')[0];
    $('#nameDiv').html(name); but no change, still a blank page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `$(xml).find('location')[0].text();`
Basically, `find` was returning an array of found results. And `[0]` gives you the first one.

Comment: I don't know why it's still showing a blank page :/ Firebug also is not showing any error.

Comment: move your `div` to inside `body` tag.

Comment: can you please see what is wrong, I have uploaded the file on http://mobile.sheridanc.on.ca/~kaushank/test1.html

Comment: could you remove the comment on first line of `bookstore.xml` and try again?

Comment: Let me try this time. *fingers crossed*

Comment: It worked! yaayyyy! @goldenparrot thanks for this invaluable suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "bookstore.xml",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : processXml
        });

function processXml(xml) {
  $("#nameDiv").html($(xml).find("location").text());
}
});
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nameDiv">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```